# jquery click event handler not being called

Tags: jquery

In my menu, I have these items:

```
<ul>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#landscape_context">Landscape Context</li>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#terrestrial_features">Terrestrial Features</li>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#aquatic_features">Aquatic Features</li>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#vegetaion_land_use">Vegetation/Land Use</li>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#additional_features">Additional Features</li>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#data_descriptions">Data Descriptions</li>
    <li class="menu_item" data-content_id="#faq">FAQ</li>
</ul>
```

Then when a user clicks on one of the items, I want to show the content for that `data-content_id`. However, nothing is happening when I click.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(".menu_item").click(function () {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

I've replaced the code with the simple alert which also does not show up when I click on a menu item.

I've looked at numerous of the other examples found here on SO, but couldn't find anything different about my solution.

Anybody see what I might be doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Put it in a DOM ready event handler.

Comment: Make sure it's wrapped in `$(document).ready(function() {...});` so that it executes after the DOM has loaded and the elements exist. Take a look at [this page](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready) of the documentation for more information.

Comment: Have you placed your code in a `$(document).ready(function() { .. });` block? Are the `li` elements dynamically appended?

Comment: Ah, yes, I moved it to my .ready() and now it works! Thanks. :)

Comment: @Pow-Ian The `.live()` function has been deprecated since version 1.7. Using that instead of simple jQuery practices makes no sense.

Comment: @James Allardice totally failed to notice .live was depreciated. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".menu_item").click(function () {
       alert(  $(this).attr("data-content_id") );
   }); 
});
```

Comment: @Explosion Pills thanks for the identation...still struggling with the editor :D

Answer (score 0):

Either the elements are loaded in the DOM *after* your script or they are loaded asynchronously.  If it's the former, just wrap everything in `$(document).ready(function () {...` (or `$(function () {...`

If it's the latter, use event delegation, such as:

```
$(document).on('click', '.menu_item', function () {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".menu_item").click(function () {
       alert($(this).attr("data-content_id"));
   }); 
});
```